# Getting JDOMException on One Machine but the same xml works fine in another

Tags: java, xml, parsing, saxparser, jdom

I am hitting an xml and getting the response back in inputstream. This xml is on the remote server.

Whenever I am running my code on the server, it gives me JDOMException,but the same code, I am running on my local machine and hitting the same xml on remote server, it is running fine.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://testwww.net/xml/android.xml");

    InputStream stream = url.openStream();
    try {
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(false);
        xmlDocument = builder.build(stream);
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
        throw new Exception("unable to read android listing document", e);
    }
```

I am not able to figure out what can be the problem here, that the same xml is running fine on one machine and not on other.

Please help me.

Thanks
Hp

Comment: can you give the full error message and stack trace

Comment: hi I am getting following error                                   Data returned {"errorDescription":"unable to read android listing document","state":"FAILURE"}

Comment: Like sbridges said, POST THE STACK TRACE.  Also, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: what is the error message on the jdom exception?  do an e.printStackTrace() before you throw your new exception

Comment: I am very sorry,but it is on the server, and i cant have access to it now,,So my sincere appologies..

Comment: One query sir,any guesses, why the same xml is behaving differently on 2 machines, some conf.issue ?

Comment: http://testwww.net/xml/android.xml doesn't exist. Maybe the XML file is cached locally when locally debugging, or something.

Comment: @Chris: Actually, the file name is formed everytime manually, here its a dummy name since it includes the company name, so can be a security issue. But, I am accessing remote xml from my local machine and is working fine but it doesnt work fine from the remote machine :(,,i m trying from a day,,but helpless..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDOMException is (presumably) happening because the "testwww.net" server is sending a response body that is not XML.  Change your program to print out the actual response stream instead of trying to parse it as XML.  That should give you some clues as to what the underlying problem is.  Even printing out the JDOMException stacktrace could be helpful ... assuming that you can get hold of that output.

---

If the problem is that you are running that code on some server and you can't get hold of debug info that your code writes to "system.out", the server logs or whatever, then you are in trouble.  You will have to use your imagination to figure out some way around that roadblock.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, It will be really very helpful.